# Is there any way to make fireworks deal no damage in 1.15?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a map that launches a specific firework at each checkpoint using commands. I'm aware that there is a way to craft fireworks so that they deal no damage. However, is there a tag for this so that theoretically, a firework could be summoned without dealing any damage to players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fireworks that were crafted with a firework star deal damage. The regular ones with just gunpowder and paper don't. The NBT tag that determines the damage is the same one as for the visual effects.